# Java: Exported JAR file doesn't load images

Tags: java, sprites, image

I am using Netbeans to create my game. The images do seem to load when I run it in Netbeans. However, the built jar file only leaves me with a blank screen.

This is how I call the images in my game.

```
public Image playerSprite = playerSprite = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("sprites\\spritesL.png");
```

I put all image resources in a folder called *sprites*, and I declared it as a Source in the Project Properties. In addition, the image files does appear in the root directory of the JAR file, but cannot seem to access it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java can be quite a pain when trying to load files that are inside the .jar. So first, try to put your *sprites* folder **outside** of your jar, on the same level. See if that works.

To load files that are inside the jar, you must use this following piece of code to retreive it's URL:

```
getClass().getResource("myimage.png")
```

So your line of code would be :

```
public Image playerSprite = playerSprite = 
   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("sprites\\spritesL.png"));
```

NOTE: You might need to call .toString() on the return value of .getResource() since it returns a URL object and .getImage() takes a String as parameter.

See if that works too. If there's any problems, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, replacing the code didn't work and instead left an [error](http://i.imgur.com/juEUOZx.png) on the console.

Comment: @LaPXL8R This is a NullPointerException. Test your code to see where it comes from (probably from the .getResource() function).

Comment: @LaPXL8R I cannot download your file and I won't, because this site is not a "debug my code" site. Please remove the link from your comment and ask a new question if another problem arises.